# java infinite linked list issue

Tags: java, list

So I'm working this problem:Given the head of a sorted linked list, delete all duplicates such that each element appears only once. Return the linked list sorted as well.And test example is [1,1,2].

```
public static class ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode next;
    ListNode() {}
    ListNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
    ListNode(int val, ListNode next) { this.val = val; this.next = next; }
}
public static ListNode deleteDuplicates(ListNode head) {
    ListNode l3=new ListNode(9);
    ListNode l4 = l3;
    if (head==null||head.next==null){
      return head;
    }
    while (head.next!=null){
        if(head.val== head.next.val){
            head=head.next;
            l3.next=head;
        }else {
            l3.next=head;
            head=head.next;
//when I debug until this line,it will creat infinite list like[1,1,1,1,.......,1,1,1]
        }
        l3=l3.next;
    }
    return l4.next;
}
```

So as you can see in the code,why will it creat infinite list when test example is[1,1,2]?

Comment: What is your code supposed to be doing? What are `l3` and `l4` and what is their purpose?

Comment: i need return a new linklist as a result, so i using l3, and using l4 is to point to l3,could you tell me why do the head  become infinite linklist when i debug?

Comment: I would start by giving meaningful names to your variables so that you can keep track of what your code should be doing when you read it. I don't see any need to return a "new" linkedlist in the assignment, and you're not doing that either since you re-use nodes from the input. I think the assignment could be as simple as `while (head.next != nil) { if(head.val == head.next.val){head.next = head.next.next;} else { head = head.next; }}` but don't have time to test.

Comment: got it! Thank you for you advice sincerely, and I have tried that before, it will only return a linknode with a node, in this example , it will return [2], but correct answer is [1,2].

Comment: You need to remember the original value of `head` and return that.